# Send a post URL and saving the unique Key from the response and send POST using Key recieved from first response

Tags: javascript, post, response, httpresponse

My knowledge is very limited but im at a complete loss of how to begin this or what commands to use while scripting this, I was hoping that it could be done in javascript, its sending the POST data to a 3rd party site, where it replies with a key for that session, I want to only save the Key from the response, then send a new POST using a different form.

Is this possible? or is this more difficult then I think it is?

```
            $(document).ready(function(){

                ajaxKey = "b71bfa6a261744ce29d91d9ab5c918f5a2b9bdcd84836feb64703faa0549c1e0";

                $("#game_reload").live("click", function() {
                    $("#game_field_blank").css("background-color","yellow");
                    $(".game_field_container").slideToggle(900);

                });
```

Edited to add snippit of code from respose viewed via firebug, that includes a demo key

Comment: First of all you need to see the format of their response. Is it only the key that they print in response? Are you doing it using AJAX?

Comment: Yes it is using ajax, here is the snippit of code that contains an example key

$(document).keypress(function(e){
     var key=e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : 0;
     if(key==37|| key == 38 || key == 39 || key == 40){
      if($.inArray(key,ar)) {
       e.preventDefault();
       return false;
      }
     }
     return true;
    });
    
    $(document).ready(function(){
            
     ajaxKey = "b71bfa6a261744ce29d91d9ab5c918f5a2b9bdcd84836feb64703faa0549c1e0";
     
     $("#game_reload").live("click", function() {
      $("#game_field_blank").css("background-color","yellow");

Comment: could you please add that code in your question so its formatted better and easy to understand

Comment: updated the post for you

Comment: please add the ajax part too

Comment: oh I apologize I am trying to code in simple javascript to send a url and copy the ajax key that was sent back as shown above, I as stated have very little knowledge.